# Derivation of the Backpropagation Algorithm

Tags: math, deep-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm studying the Backpropagation algorithm and I want to derive it by myself. Therefore, I've constructed a very simple network with one input layer, one hidden layer and one output layer. You can find the details in the graphic.

The network can be found here:
[image]

t is the true output, i is the input, z and w are the weights. Moreover I have the activation function ϕ(x).

I think that I have understood the algorithm more or less, so I've started with the following error function:
[image]

That function should be correct, isn't it? The next step is to calculate the partial derivative:

[image]

For me that seems to be correct, but is that right up to here (Especially the formal math aspects)? I'm asking, because i have so problems with the next steps (derivating to the z's...)

Thanks for helping!

Comment: This is a duplicate from [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4260877) or vice versa.  If you do a web search for "derive backpropogation" there are some useful hits so maybe we don't have to reinvent the wheel here, or else you can look there and then come back here and post an answer to your own question in case others can benefit from it too.

Comment: There is an excellent derivation of the Back Propagation algorithm available at http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html.  And additional outstanding reference is a video series Grant Sanderson put together on his YouTube channel, 3 Brown, 1 Blue. (https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDNU6R1_67000Dx_ZCJB-3pi)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is off topic here and was cross-posted to a more suitable site.